# Undefined reference to strcmp with toolchain

Tags: c, toolchain, bare-metal

I am trying to write a simple bare-metal program on the raspberry pi, but when I am trying to use to use `strcmp` I am getting the following error:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld -o main.elf  -T ./src/memmap vectors.o led.o main.o uart.o general.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text.startup+0x80): undefined reference to `strcmp'
```

This is my make file:

```
ARMGNU = arm-none-eabi


ARMGNU ?= arm-none-eabi

AOPS = --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -march=armv6
COPS = -Wall -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mhard-float 

LIBRARIES= -I ./include -I ./src 

all : kernel.img 
    rm -f *.bin
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.elf
    rm -f *.list
    rm -f *.hex

vectors.o : ./src/vectors.s
    $(ARMGNU)-as $(AOPS) $(LIBRARIES) -mfpu=vfp ./src/vectors.s -o vectors.o

main.o : ./src/main.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) $(LIBRARIES) -c ./src/main.c -o main.o

led.o : ./src/led.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) $(LIBRARIES) -c ./src/led.c -o led.o

uart.o : ./src/uart.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) $(LIBRARIES) -c ./src/uart.c -o uart.o

general.o : ./src/general.c
    $(ARMGNU)-gcc $(COPS) $(LIBRARIES) -c ./src/general.c -o general.o

kernel.img : ./src/memmap vectors.o main.o led.o uart.o general.o
    $(ARMGNU)-ld -o main.elf  -T ./src/memmap vectors.o led.o main.o uart.o general.o
    $(ARMGNU)-objdump -D main.elf > main.list
    $(ARMGNU)-objcopy main.elf kernel.img -O binary


clean:
    rm -r *.img
```

Comment: Is there a libc you can link with? Otherwise, write your own strcmp.

Comment: `-nostdlib` seems pretty clear. You need to write your own `strcmp`, then (fortunately that's not rocket science).

Comment: @Jongware I removed the `-nostdlib`, same error, @Charlie Burns I found the libc.a in the toolchain, how can I link it? I tried also `COPS = -Wall -O2 -lc -ffreestanding -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -mhard-float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive strcmp (your compiler should optimize away the recursion though)

```
int strcmp(const char *a,const char *b){
  if (! (*a | *b)) return 0;
  return (*a!=*b) ? *a-*b : strcmp(++a,++b);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but for example if I would like to allocate memory dynamically, than still have the same problem.

Comment: @run I'm not sure what you mean.  The parameters don't need additional memory, it take pointers to existing allocated char arrays.  Any allocation is done prior to calling strcmp, otherwise you wouldn't have strings to compare.

Comment: Here I don't need dynamic memory allocation, but in case if I need it I will run into the same problem as now.

Comment: @run - if you are going to need a malloc()/free() too then you may consider using musl libc otherwise you can adapt a small version of malloc out of K&R which basically does memory pools and adds/removes program memory with the brk()/sbrk() syscalls